# Alternar cambio de "src" en video html5 con iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Tengo el siguiente código funcional en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/slowdmelendez360/pen/WNxOrgb)

Adjunto el contenido del pen.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <video id="theVideo" width="640" height="480" controls>
        <div id="dragHandle"></div>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video><br>
    <div id=buttons>    
        <li><button id="btn1" class="btn">Chapter 1</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn2" class="btn">Chapter 2</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn3" class="btn">Chapter 3</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn4" class="btn">Chapter 4</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn5" class="btn">Chapter 5</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn6" class="btn">Chapter 6</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn7" class="btn">Chapter 7</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn8" class="btn">Chapter 8</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn9" class="btn">Chapter 9</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn10" class="btn">Chapter 10</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn11" class="btn">Chapter 11</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn12" class="btn">Chapter 12</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn13" class="btn">Chapter 13</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn14" class="btn">Chapter 14</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn15" class="btn">Chapter 15</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn16" class="btn">TV_Episode 1</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn17" class="btn">TV_Episode 2</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn18" class="btn">TV_Episode 3</button></li>
        <li><button id="btn19" class="btn">TV_Episode 4</button></li>
 </div><br><br>
</div><!-- end of wrapper -->
```

JavaScript:

```
(function(){
var theVid = document.getElementById("theVideo");
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('btn'), function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        switch (e.target.id){
        case "btn1":
                 theVid.src = "Captain_Video01.mp4";
                break;
            case "btn2":
                 theVid.src = "Captain_Video02.mp4";
                break;
            case "btn3":
                 theVid.src = "mp4/Captain_Video03.mp4"; 
                break;
            case "btn4":
                 theVid.src = "mp4/Captain_Video04.mp4"; 
                break;
            case "btn5":
                 theVid.src = "mp4/Captain_Video05.mp4";
                break;
            case "btn6":
                 theVid.src = "mp4/Captain_Video06.mp4";
                break;
            case "btn7":
                 theVid.src = "mp4/Captain_Video07.mp4"; 
                break;
            case "btn15":
                 theVid.src = "Captain_Video15.mp4"; 
                break;
            default:
                 console.log(e.target.id);
                }
            })
    })
Draggable.create("#theVideo",
 {type:"x,y", edgeResistance:0.65, bounds:"#wrapper", throwProps:true});
}())
```

Lo he utilizado y acoplado a mis necesidades, sin embargo quiero saber si hay alguna manera de implementarlo junto a "iframe".

Es decir, cuando se hace clic en el `botón 1`, entonces te reproduce la URL que se le ha introducido en el código de Javascript.
Yo quiero seguir manteniendo ese funcionamiento, pero que al momento de hacer clic en el `botón 2`, aparezca un iframe (con su respectivo contenido) por encima del reproductor html.

Y que al momento de hacer clic nuevamente en el `botón 1`, se muestre nuevamente el reproductor de video con su respectivo `source`

Comment: Una opción es agregar un container donde va el video y reemplazar el contenido con el video o iframe correspondiente cada vez que presiona un boton.

Comment: Vale. ¿Cómo sería posible hacerlo funcional?